# Sum up a column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have four tables in my database which is Star Schema Design. Those tables are

1. Product_DM (Product_Id, Product_Name)
2. Shop_DM (Branch_Id, Branch_Name, Branch_State)
3. Date_DM (Date_Id as Date, Day, Month and Year). Day and Month and Year values are populated based on Date_Id.
4. Revenue_FT (Product_id, Branch_Id, Date_Id, Quantity)

What I want to have is I want to look at 5 BRANCH OR SHOP which sells most products last five years of Boxing day.

```
SELECT 
    RF.BRANCH_ID,
    SD.BRANCH_NAME,
    SD.BRANCH_STATE,
    PD.PRODUCT_NAME,
    SELF_RF.TOTAL,
    FORMAT ( DD.[date], 'd', 'en-US' ) AS 'Great Britain English Result'
FROM 
    PRODUCT_DM  AS PD,
    SHOP_DM     AS SD,
    DATE_DM     AS DD,
    REVENUE_FT  AS RF
JOIN 
    (SELECT BRANCH_ID, [date], SUM(quantity) AS TOTAL
     FROM REVENUE_FT
     GROUP BY BRANCH_ID, [date]) AS SELF_RF ON SELF_RF.BRANCH_ID = RF.BRANCH_ID 
                                            AND SELF_RF.[date] = RF.[date]
WHERE   
    RF.BRANCH_ID = SD.BRANCH_ID  
    AND SD.BRANCH_STATE = 'NSW'         
    AND RF.[date] = DD.[date]     
    AND DD.[day] = 26            
    AND DD.[month] = 12            
    AND DD.[year] BETWEEN 2012 AND 2018
ORDER BY 
    SELF_RF.TOTAL DESC;
```

This is the query I have and this is the result:

[image]

The problem is it is not summing up different products and different dates (for example `12/26/2013` and `12/26/2014` should also sum up). I know I am doing something wrong in my query but I needed a hand.

Comment: you have `PRODUCT_DM ` in your query but it is not join to any table. So effectively you are doing a `CROSS JOIN` to it

Comment: What exactly does `5 BRANCH OR SHOP which sells most products` means ?  `most products` is in terms of total quantity sold or total number of products ? Also please avoid such style of join and please use ANSI style of table join

Comment: @Squirrel Sorry, for confusion. Yes. 5 Branch means as u can see Branch_Id  and most products means Total in quantity. In the picture it has 4 `branch_id 1`. If it sums up it would become like this `branch_id` 1 will have `total` 400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See an example below where you're able to get the top 5 branch / shops which have had the highest sales over the past 5 boxing days.

It's an example based off your listed table structure above.

```
;with GetBranchDetailsAndData
as
(
    --Joins the date table, sales, and shop details to get the branch details and quantity per transaction
    SELECT 
        c.Branch_Id,
        c.Branch_Name,
        c.Branch_State,
        a.Quantity
    FROM 
        Revenue_FT a
    INNER JOIN 
        DATE_DM  b
    ON 
        a.Date_Id = b.Date_Id
    INNER JOIN 
        Shop_DM c
    ON 
        c.Branch_Id = a.Branch_Id
    WHERE 
        [DAY] = 26 AND 
        [Month] = 12
        AND [Year] BETWEEN 2012 AND 2017 --Boxing days in 2012 - 2017
        --You could also filter on a specific state in the where clause

),
SUMDetailsAndData
as
(
    SELECT
        Branch_ID,
        Branch_Name,
        Branch_State, 
        SUM(Quantity) as [Quantity] --Sum quantity per branch
    FROM 
        GetBranchDetailsAndData
    GROUP BY
        Branch_ID,
        Branch_Name,
        Branch_State
), 
GetTop5
as
(
    SELECT
        Branch_ID,
        Branch_Name,
        Branch_State,
        Quantity,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Quantity DESC) as [QuantityOrder] --DENSE RANK to get the quantity order 
    FROM 
        SUMDetailsAndData
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    GetTop5
WHERE 
    QuantityOrder <= 5 --Where the quantity order less or equal to 5. This will return multiple rows if there is multiple with the same number in the top 5. 
ORDER BY 
    QuantityOrder
```

Here is a snippet below which I used to generate testing data.

```
--Create tables
CREATE TABLE Product_DM (Product_Id bigint identity(1,1), Product_Name NVARCHAR(200))
CREATE TABLE Shop_DM (Branch_Id bigint identity(1,1), Branch_Name NVARCHAR(100), Branch_State NVARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE Date_DM (Date_Id bigint identity(1,1), [Day] int, [Month] int, [Year] int)
CREATE TABLE Revenue_FT (Product_id bigint, Branch_Id bigint, Date_Id bigint, Quantity bigint)
--Insert Data
INSERT INTO Product_DM (Product_Name) VALUES ('Test Product'),('Test Product2')
INSERT INTO Shop_DM (Branch_Name, Branch_State) VALUES 
('Branch1', 'State1'), ('Branch2', 'State1'), ('Branch3', 'State1'), ('Branch4', 'State1'), ('Branch5', 'State1'), 
('Branch6', 'State1'), ('Branch7', 'State1'), ('Branch8', 'State1'), ('Branch9', 'State1'), ('Branch10', 'State1')

DECLARE @DateStart date = '2010-01-01', @DateEnd date = '2018-01-01'
WHILE(@DateStart <= @DateEnd) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DATE_DM ([day], [month], [year]) VALUES (DATEPART(dd, @datestart), DATEPART(MM, @datestart), DATEPART(YYYY, @datestart))
    SET @DateStart = DATEADD(dd, 1, @DateStart)
END

--Insert random product sales
DECLARE @MinProduct int = 1, @MaxProduct int = 2
DECLARE @MinBranch int = 1, @MaxBranch int = 10
DECLARE @MinDate int = 1, @MaxDate int = 2923
DECLARE @Startloop int = 1, @EndLoop int = 200000

WHILE @Startloop <= @EndLoop
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Revenue_FT VALUES (
            ROUND(((@MaxProduct - @MinProduct) * RAND() + @MinProduct), 0), 
            ROUND(((@MaxBranch - @MinBranch) * RAND() + @MinBranch), 0), 
            ROUND(((@MaxDate - @MinDate) * RAND() + @MinDate), 0), 1)

    SET @Startloop = @Startloop + 1
END
```

Example output below:

[image: Output]

Comment: This is working like a charm. I am so appreciated your effort for answering and explaining stuffs. Thank you so much